# what is a controller in sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I was asked why "I was creating complex Ruby variables in my view.
Shouldn't have these variables been declared by my controller?"

Is my **sinatra controller** my **.rb** file? I have one .rb file and view views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each Sinatra route can be considered its own controller in a typical MVC setup. For your example:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
get "/foo" do
  # This might take many lines of excellent code to form your data
  @data = some_complex_array_hash_combo
  haml :foo
end
```

And then in `foo.haml`:

```haml
:javascript
  var data = #{@data.to_json};
```

Comment: why do I have to use `@data` and not `data`?

Comment: @Radek Because instance variables are made available to the Haml template by Sinatra `haml` helper, but local variables are not.

Answer (score 17):

You can setup the idea of controllers by doing (in 1.9.2) this at the top of your main .rb file

```
Dir.glob("controllers/*.rb").each { |r| require_relative r }
```

This will require_relative each .rb file in a folder called controllers/

From there you can implement normal routing like you would've previously done in the main .rb file. Please have a look at [rstat.us](https://github.com/hotsh/rstat.us) on Github.

Edit: Rstat.us has gone rails3 and while still helpful you may have to go back numerous commits on the master branch to find how it was used.

Comment: This comment deserves more karma. Very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Sinatra out of the box does not have a standard MVC framework. So while you don't want to leave everything in the main view file, you also don't technically have a "controller" to put this in. Splitting up your application into different functionality would probably be the best approach to keep it simple. Pull large areas of functionality out into separate classes and small things into helper libraries.

Looking at how others do this might help out, this post should have some good examples for you to study: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075758/real-life-examples-of-sinatra-applications

If an MVC framework becomes something you really think you need, take a look at Padrino (http://padrinorb.com)

Slightly related post:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14293/ruby-sinatra-best-practices-for-project-structure

Comment: Helpers are classes meant to assist views. http://ididitmyway.heroku.com/past/2010/4/25/sinatra_helpers/

Answer (score 1):

@CaleyWoods : thank you for the reference to rstat.us

For those who are looking for the Sinatra version, here is a link to a Sinatra commit:
https://github.com/hotsh/rstat.us/tree/00b27505681d80b3943fd9b9e9791f664a04cf39

(so you don't have to trawl through the commit history ;-) )

Comment: And https://github.com/hotsh/rstat.us/blob/00b27505681d80b3943fd9b9e9791f664a04cf39/rstatus.rb#L79   L#79 shows the Dir.glob statement that allows you to use a controllers/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is just for inheritance later if you have controllers that inherit from ApplicationController. Good luck!
If your using a config.ru file for your app then this may help.

```
require 'active_support'
require 'sinatra/base'

APP_ROOT = Pathname.new(File.expand_path('../', __FILE__))

# We have to do this in case we have controllers that inherit from each   other.
Dir[APP_ROOT.join('app', 'controllers', '*.rb')].each do |controller_file|
  filename = File.basename(controller_file).gsub('.rb', '')
  autoload ActiveSupport::Inflector.camelize(filename), controller_file
end
```

This assumes you put that code into your config.ru but you could put in your application file also and be sure to adjust for directory structure.